# Salt does not recognise packages in SLS file

Tags: configuration, nagios, salt-stack

I am quite a noob to Salt as well as Nagios but either I am missing something obvious or it is a Bug.

I downloaded the nagios-formula in /srv/formulas and have set up rest of master & minions. I am able to do basic apache installations on all minions (3 vagrant machines - 1 master and 3 minions including master machine minion). What I want to achieve is have naagios server on master and NRPE client and plugins on minions so my top.sls looks like:

`base:
  'smaster*':
    - nagios.server
  '*sagent.learn.com':
    - nagios.plugins
    - nagios.nrpe.server:
        cfg_dir: /etc/nagios/nrpe.d/
    - nagios.nrpe:
        cfg_dir: /etc/nagios/nrpe.d/`

Now on agents - nagios.plugins gets installed but nothing else changes. Even a syntax error in "nrpe.server" is not complained about. Also all executions of state.highstate run fine - but without any intended effect. Also if I miss any of cfg_dir - it will complain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put config data in your top file. Your `cfg_dir` options should be pillar data or in the sls files directly.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that helps. Lack of error message is not very helpful